# Rails SQL Queries on join table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I've got a rails app with the following models:

```
class Partner < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timesheets
  has_many :timeslots, through: :timesheets
  # ...
end

class Timeslot < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :timesheets
  has_many :partners, through: :timesheets
  # ...
end

class Timesheet < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :partner
  belongs_to :timeslot
  # ...
end
```

Notice how the Timesheet serves as a join table of sorts for storing Partner-Timeslot pairs. I want to get all such Partner-Timeslot pairs where the timeslots fulfill some condition. I don't actually care at all about the Timesheet object for this query. I've worked out that the appropriate SQL is something along the lines of:

```
SELECT partners.*, timeslots.*
FROM timesheets
  JOIN partners
    ON timesheets.partner_id = partners.id
  JOIN timeslots
    ON timesheets.timeslot_id = timeslots.id
WHERE (...some condition logic that I can figure out on my own...)
```

Notice how although I'm querying the timesheets table I actually only want Partner and Timeslot objects.

Can you do this with Rails?

Is there a better way to do it?

Miscellaneous info:

I'm using MySQL as the database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can certainly do this in Rails.  You could start with:

```
partner_timeslots = Partner.joins([ timesheets: :timeslot ]).select('partners.*, timeslots.*')
```

This will generate the following query:

```
select partners.*, timeslots.* 
from partners 
  inner join timesheets on timesheets.partner_id = partners.id 
  inner join timeslots on timeslots.id = timesheets.timeslot_id
```

If trying on console, try `partner_timeslots.to_yaml` to see all `partners` and `timeslots` attributes returned.

Comment: I found to_json to be more helpful than to_yaml, but thanks! I think I'm finally starting to understand this stuff.